# Java constructors issues

Tags: java

My objective is to create a Dragster and Dragrace class. My dragster class is complete, but I'm lost on how to finish my DragRace class. The main method is supposed to display results like this.

> Dragster characteristics: Reaction Time: 0.6, Torque: 1000, Traction: 0.8286078156824775, Burn Time: 3
>
> Dragster time: 6.634217763058126 seconds.

I have to create an array that holds 5 dragsters then displays the results for each one.

```
public class Dragster {
    private int burnTime;
    private double reactionTime;
    private int torque;
    private double traction; 

    public Dragster(double reactionTime, int torque, double traction, int     burnTime) {
    this.reactionTime = reactionTime;
    this.torque = torque;
    this.traction = traction;
    this.burnTime = burnTime;

}

private double conditionTires(double time){
    double effectiveness = 2.5*(Math.exp((time * time - (10 * time) + 25) / 50))/Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI);
    return effectiveness;

}

public void burnout(){
    traction = traction * conditionTires(burnTime);
}

public double race(){
    double TORQUE2TIME = 5000;
    double raceTime = reactionTime + (1/(torque/ TORQUE2TIME)*conditionTires(burnTime));
    return raceTime;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Reaction Time:" + reactionTime + ", Torque:" + torque + "Traction:" + traction +
            "Burn Time:" + burnTime;

}
}


public class DragRace {

    private DragRace{

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Dragster> DragsterList = new ArrayList<Dragster>();
        Dragster car1 = new Dragster(0.6, 1000, 0.9, 3);
        Dragster car2 = new Dragster(0.4, 800, 1.0, 5);
        Dragster car3 = new Dragster(0.5, 1200, 0.95, 7);
        Dragster car4 = new Dragster(0.3, 1200, 0.95, 1);
        Dragster car5 = new Dragster(0.4, 900, 0.9, 6);
        DragsterList.add(car1);
        DragsterList.add(car2);
        DragsterList.add(car3);
        DragsterList.add(car4);
        DragsterList.add(car5);
        DragsterList.toString();



    }
}
```

I'm lost in the dragrace class as what to do next. If anyone could give some insight.

Comment: You have to have a race method that would iterate through all the Dragster  objects and calculate the race time and display the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
public void printResults() {
    for (Dragster d: DragsterList) {
        System.out.println(d.toString());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Dragster time:" + d.race());
    }
}
```

Basically, you just need to loop through each car in your list, print the car, and race it once.

Answer (score 0):

The toString method you are using at the end of the program is converting the list itself to a string, which isn't what you want.

You will want to call toString() on each dragster individually